# How does association within vapor or dissociation within liquid affect the ideal nature of a binary solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, vapor-pressure

As I understand, when there is positive deviation of a binary solution from Raoult's Law, the equilibrium partial pressure curve approach ideality (i.e a straight line dependence of equilibrium partial pressure and pure component vapor pressure) when the mole fraction approaches unity for any one the components. This is true except when there is association within vapor or dissociation within liquid. What is this association and dissociation and how does this affect the ideal nature?